# Crash docker-compose dockerpycreds.errors.InitializationError

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-18.04

Output of `docker-compose version`

```
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad0
docker-py version: 3.7.0
CPython version: 2.7.15rc1
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017
```

Output of `docker version`

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.1
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       4c52b90
  Built:            Wed Jan  9 19:02:44 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Output of `docker-compose config`

```
services:
  my-test:
    image: hello-world
    network_mode: bridge
version: '2.1'
```

Stacktrace / full error message:

```
root@home-bot:~/temp# docker-compose up
Pulling my-test (hello-world:)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main
    command()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 127, in perform_command
    handler(command, command_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1080, in up
    to_attach = up(False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 1076, in up
    silent=options.get('--quiet-pull'),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/project.py", line 475, in up
    svc.ensure_image_exists(do_build=do_build, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 352, in ensure_image_exists
    self.pull(silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1217, in pull
    return progress_stream.get_digest_from_pull(event_stream)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/progress_stream.py", line 101, in get_digest_from_pull
    for event in events:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/service.py", line 1182, in _do_pull
    output = self.client.pull(repo, **pull_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 381, in pull
    header = auth.get_config_header(self, registry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 48, in get_config_header
    client._auth_configs, registry, credstore_env=client.credstore_env
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 322, in resolve_authconfig
    return authconfig.resolve_authconfig(registry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 235, in resolve_authconfig
    cfg = self._resolve_authconfig_credstore(registry, store_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 262, in _resolve_authconfig_credstore
    store = self._get_store_instance(credstore_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/docker/auth.py", line 287, in _get_store_instance
    name, environment=self._credstore_env
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dockerpycreds/store.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.program
dockerpycreds.errors.InitializationError: docker-credential-osxkeychain not installed or not available in PATH
```

---

Additional information
OS version / distribution:
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)

Comment: Please ask and explain a question in your question. Don't just post output, error messages, and OS versions. [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's also possible that you've set the `"credStore"` of your Docker client to be `"osxkeychain"` in your `~/.docker/config.json`.

link issues:
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6458#issuecomment-454064994

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I'm still investigating but a temporary fix is to remove the docker configuration in your home

```
$ mv $HOME/.docker to_something_else
```

Comment: Same issue, same platform.  Reinstall of docker and docker-compose did not helped.  The above fix did.

Answer (score 5):

I run my docker compose in GCE.

Deleting `~/.docker/config.json` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

For [me](https://github.com/pgRouting/docker-pgrouting/issues/11) installing the missing tool fixed the problem:

```sh
sudo apt install golang-docker-credential-helpers
```